# The derivative of an integral function with indicator and max function as integrand

Tags: integration, open-problems, differential-calculus, problem-solving

I encounter the following type of problem:

\begin{equation}
F(x) = \int_a^b \mathbf{1}_{\{v+x-h(v)\geq 0\}}\max\{h(v)-y-x,0\}dv
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{1}_{\{z\geq 0\}}=1$ if event $z\geq 0$ occurs, and zero otherwise. $y>0$ is constant.

I am not sure how to apply fundamental theorem of calculus (or may be something else?) to get $\frac{dF(x)}{dx}$. I think in $\frac{dF(x)}{dx}$, it should contain something like $\delta
(x)$?

Comment: (1) Do you have two functions $h$ and $g$? (2) What is known about them?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan I changed the post a little bit. The function $g$ is a general continuous function

Comment: Just to simplify, replace $h(v):=g(v)+p$. It's still continuous and still as arbitrary as $g$. Also, say $y:=c+w>0$.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan So is there any general guideline to solve this type of problem? Can we directly apply Leibniz integral rule?

Comment: I'll think about it, first let's fix things up.

Comment: @kimkevin: Since the right side depends on $y$, you should make $F$ depend on $y$ too.